# Unable to rectify the cause during installation of java and setting java path in batch file

Tags: windows, batch-file

I need to install java and set the Java path. 
I'm able to install java and can  see two folders in C:\Program Files (x86)\Java i.e Jre and Jdk .

But when i'm trying to set the JAVA_PATH in my code but i can't its path on command propmt echo command i.e   @echo JAVA_HOME = %JAVA_HOME%. Though i have started scripting today itself so unable to rectify where i'm missing out ?

here is the code that i tried  :-

```
     @echo off

    for /f %%j in ("java.exe") do (
     set JAVA_HOME=%%~dp$PATH:j
     **@echo JAVA_HOME = %JAVA_HOME%**
    ECHO "ok1"
    PAUSE
    )
   if %JAVA_HOME%.==. (
   @echo java.exe not found 
    PAUSE
    CD C:\Users\Pathfinder\Desktop
   ECHO "Time In"

    jdk-6u43-windows-i586.exe /s "/v\"/qn ADDLOCAL=ALL  REBOOT=Suppress JAVAUPDATE=0  
     CUSTOM=1\""

     timeout /t 10 /nobreak
     ECHO "Time Out"
     set path="C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jre6\bin";%path%

     @echo PATH= %path%
     set JAVA_HOME="C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jdk1.6.0_43\bin";%JAVA_HOME%

     **@echo JAVA_HOME = %JAVA_HOME%**

     PAUSE
     ) else (
     @echo JAVA_HOME = %JAVA_HOME%

   PAUSE
    )
```

After one time execution of my batch file means process completed after double clicking the batch file when i'm again double clicking the batch file then its going to 'IF' condition again i.e " java.exe not found "  .

Comment: I used an anternative way of checking java install, checking registry value in `{HKLM|HKCU}\Software\[Wow6432Node\]JavaSoft\Java Runtime Environment\{version}\JavaHome`

Answer (score 1):

Delayed variable expansion: all your variables into parenthesis are evaluated before execution.

Here you can't use `SETLOCAL ENABLEDELAYEDEXPANSION` because you need to get variables out of batch.

So you must rewrite your batch without variables within parenthesis:

```
@echo off
SET JAVA_HOME=
for /f %%j in ("java.exe") do set JAVA_HOME=%%~dp$PATH:j
IF DEFINED JAVA_HOME GOTO :JAVA_FOUND

:JAVA_NOT_FOUND
@echo java.exe not found 
PAUSE
CD C:\Users\Pathfinder\Desktop
ECHO "Time In"
jdk-6u43-windows-i586.exe /s "/v\"/qn ADDLOCAL=ALL  REBOOT=Suppress JAVAUPDATE=0 CUSTOM=1\""
timeout /t 10 /nobreak
ECHO "Time Out"
set path="C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jre6\bin";%path%
@echo PATH= %path%
set JAVA_HOME="C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jdk1.6.0_43\bin";%JAVA_HOME%
@echo JAVA_HOME = %JAVA_HOME%
GOTO :END

:JAVA_FOUND
@echo JAVA_HOME =  %JAVA_HOME%
ECHO "ok1"
PAUSE
@echo JAVA_HOME = %JAVA_HOME%
PAUSE

:END
```

I left optimization up to you.

Also check `START /WAIT` instead of `timeout`.

Comment: :Thanx for replying. Just tried your code and now i'm able to get PATH and JAVA_HOME . But when i see the environment variable then i cant see these variables set in Control Panel\System and Security\System\Advanced System Properties\variables............

I think code does not set them permanently. If i double click the batch file for the second time its showing message that "java.exe not found".

Comment: Of course not: changes in environment are made in process base. To change system/user environment variables you must write registry keys. Check `REG.EXE` for such and be very careful!

Comment: :- ya right but this batch file i have to run on client side. This means i dont have to do it manually. So is it possible to do in batch file ?

Comment: Check `REG.EXE /?`. You can manipulate registry in batch with it.