# Unable to set JAVA_HOME path into environment variable

Tags: batch-file

I'm able to get PATH and JAVA_HOME on command prompt . But when i see the environment variable then i cant see these variables set in Control Panel\System and Security\System\Advanced System Properties\variables............ I think code does not set them permanently. If i double click the batch file for the second time its showing message that "java.exe not found".

I'm unable to figure out where i'm missing out or  written code wrongly?
**i'm working on Windows 7**

Code Tried :-

```
  @echo off
  SET JAVA_HOME=
  for /f %%j in ("java.exe") do set JAVA_HOME=%%~dp$PATH:j
  IF DEFINED JAVA_HOME GOTO :JAVA_FOUND

 :JAVA_NOT_FOUND
  @echo java.exe not found 
  PAUSE
  CD C:\Users\Pathfinder\Desktop
  ECHO "Time In"
  jdk-6u43-windows-i586.exe /s "/v\"/qn ADDLOCAL=ALL  REBOOT=Suppress JAVAUPDATE=0 
  CUSTOM=1\""
  timeout /t 10 /nobreak
  ECHO "Time Out"
  set path="C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jre6\bin";%path%
  @echo PATH= %path%
  set JAVA_HOME="C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jdk1.6.0_43\bin";%JAVA_HOME%
  @echo JAVA_HOME = %JAVA_HOME%
  GOTO :END

  :JAVA_FOUND
   @echo JAVA_HOME =  %JAVA_HOME%
   ECHO "ok1"
   PAUSE
   @echo JAVA_HOME = %JAVA_HOME%
   PAUSE

  :END
```

Comment: @Endoro : Now onwards i'vl do it .
But i have tried the above code . Can u please rectify where i'm wrong ?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Unable to rectify the cause during installation of java and setting java path in batch file](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18444317/unable-to-rectify-the-cause-during-installation-of-java-and-setting-java-path-in)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is the answer . As i'm working on windows 7 so setx works here.
It will SET your environment variable .

```
@echo off
for /f %%j in ("java.exe") do (
set JAVA_HOME=%%~dp$PATH:j
 )
if %JAVA_HOME%.==. (
@echo java.exe not found
PAUSE
CD C:\Users\Pathfinder\Desktop
jdk-6u43-windows-i586.exe /s "/v\"/qn ADDLOCAL=ALL  REBOOT=Suppress JAVAUPDATE=0   
CUSTOM=1\""
setx PATH "%path%;C:\Progra~2\Java\jdk1.6.0_43\bin"
setx JAVA_HOME "C:\Progra~2\Java\jdk1.6.0_43"
) else (
@echo JAVA_HOME = %JAVA_HOME%
PAUSE
)
```

Answer (score 3):

Use `SETX` to permanently set an environment variable in Windows.

Comment: just tried it few mins back n its working. Thanx for your reply :)

Comment: ERROR: invalid syntax. Type "SETX /?" for usage